# Is it possible to make ArangoDB portable?

Tags: arangodb

I am a developer working on a multi-platform desktop applications and I am looking to use arangodb.  however, my application is and must remain portable.... to be able to run from a usb stick, a hard drive or a network drive (not sure bout this one yet)

I am switching over from orient-db, which I chose because it was multi-model and portable (except for requiring java)....but lets say it seems like orientdb has major issues.

How can I go about learning how to package arangodb with my application and run the service on demand only when my application is started?

Comment: `sudo service arangodb3 start` runs ArangoDB on Linux. By portable, do you mean cross-platform, or is this a bootable USB you're talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the ArangoDB 3.1 Release all packaging is being moved to cmake/cpack.

Aside of the general install scripts [all logic for this is in `cmake packges/`](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/tree/devel/cmake/packages) and [under the respective directories under `Installation`](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/tree/devel/Installation).

You can run ArangoDB completely without configuration file as [all settings can be specified via commandline argument too](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Administration/Configuration/index.html).

Depending on the installation target, the means of starting a service can be different; naming [Windows services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Linux system V init scripts](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/devel/Installation/debian/arangodb.init), [Linux systemd unit files](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/devel/Installation/systemd/arangodb3.service.in).

Similar to other install processes, [you should launch it once to provision the access credetials](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/devel/Installation/debian/postinst#L14).

ArangoDBs windows installer is not mandatory, [as the cookbook for the xcopy install demonstrates](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/cookbook/Administration/XCopyInstallWindows.html).

In the end you will have to launch ArangoDB the same way as you launched OrientDB; just that the Arangodb binary has to be chosen according to your system needs the same way you have chosen the java interpreter for OrientDB.

You should be able to run the ArangoDB binaries and its js libraries from any source drive; startup speed may vary depending on the drive speed. I would however recommend running it with the database folders (`--database.directory`) pointing to a local spinning disk or locally attached storage since running that on network drives is not supported.